# Disable all skins in Oracle Webcenter Portal

Tags: oracle, webcenter

Is it possible to disable all skins in Oracle Webcenter Portal?

I get about 300kb of css as default. I don't want to use any of the default css since I'd like to write my own css.

I've tried to extend the "empty" skin without success. 
Also I've tried to extend a non existing skin with the result just getting the default skin anyway.

I'm looking for a way to disable all skins, and use a css in the Web content folder instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a custom skin where you override the ADF component selectors as well. That should help you start with an "empty" looking skin.

I don't think you can disable the basic skins that come with ADF itself. You'll probably need to look at other caching strategies as described by the stack.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The minimum thing you can start with is extending from the Simple skin which is very small skin

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to get rid of all stying. The CSS is also used for standard WebCenter Portal components, such as the Administration Console and the page editing functionality.